# log affecting listview?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, logging, android-asynctask

Quick question, I have a listview that's populated from a database through an AsyncTask. I use an if statement to decide which db method to get a cursor from. The db methods work great outside an asynctask, but only works inside the asynctask when the Log code is there.

```
if (i == 1) {
    c = cdb.getFive();
    Log.d("TAG5", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(c));
}
```

works, but

```
if (i == 1) {
    c = cdb.getFive();
    //Log.d("TAG5", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(c));
}
```

doesn't work. Any ideas why?

EDIT - That code is in `doInBackground()`

Comment: You should post some more code. Otherwise magic indeed. :P

Comment: what code do you want, the full activity and db methods?

Comment: @BillGary Maybe you should post the code for the method `dumpCursorToString`. And what exactly means works/doesn't work? Exceptions?

Comment: `dumpCursorToString` is from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#dumpCursorToString%28android.database.Cursor%29 and it throws no errors, it just doesn't populate the listview. The listview is in a tabhost if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `c.moveToFirst()` method before reading any data from `Cursor`.

Actually, method `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString()` calls method `moveToPosition()`. What's why your code is working with logging and doesn't working without it.